# extjs alert response

Tags: php, extjs

I have the following code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'newRecord.php',
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'json',
    params: {
        "author" : list.Author,
        "title" : list.Title,
        "manufacturer" : list.Manufacturer,
        "product_group" : list.ProductGroup
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.author);
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('Failure');
    }
});
```

the alert returns undefined however my php returns {"author":"The author here"}

what is the mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer after some research:

The trick is to put this in success function

```
// resp is the XmlHttpRequest object
var options = Ext.decode(resp.responseText).author;
alert(options);
```

Comment: The parameter `type: 'json'` in your request's configuration is useless. Where did you took it?

Comment: But I can't find it in the documentation. Maybe I'm just missing something. Can you give me a link?

Comment: Update: it did work without the type json, since I didn't try removing it after I added the two lines.